# Manipulate breaks when using the RegionFunction option?

Tags: manipulate

For some reason, the code below breaks when using the regionfunction option with Manipulate. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

```
Manipulate[
 SliceVectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, -2, 
   2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z >= 0]], {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: A bug. 12.3 work fine and  13.3.1 does not work.

Comment: TY.  So I'm not crazy.  : ) I'm running 13.2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version
"13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"
```

**A work-around:** add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`:

```
Manipulate[
 SliceVectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 + s},
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z >= 0]], {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Note:**

#### [\$PerformanceGoal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PerformanceGoal.html)

[image]

We can replicate the issue using the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`:

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z >= 0]]
```

[image]